# Python adding titles to x & y axis dash app

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am attempting to create a dash app for creating a scatter plot of some data.. Would someone be able to give me a tip for showing titles on the x & y axis of the plot? It seems like most documentation I am finding online seems like its for IPython. Layouts are defined in this format:

```
layout = dict(
        title= 'Rank',
        ticklen= 5,
        gridwidth= 2,
    )
```

But my dash app looks more like this format: ***EDIT to include all code below***

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



df = pd.read_csv('boilerData.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')

app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1('Heating System Temperature Data Visulation'), 
    html.Center('The purpose of the scatter plot below is to prove if a temperature reset strategy is implemented on the hydronic heating system. At various outside air temperature conditions, the hot water temperature should fluctuate to save energy.'),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='hwst-vs-oat',
        figure={
            'data': [
                go.Scatter(
                    x = df.OAT,
                    y = df.HWST,
                    mode = 'markers',
                    marker = dict(
                        color = '#FFBAD2',
                        line = dict(width = 1)
                    )
                )
            ],
            'layout':{
            'title':'Scatter Plot of OAT versus HWST',
            'xaxis':{
                'title':'whatever you want x to be'
            },
            'yaxis':{
                 'title':'whatever you want y to be'
            }
        }
    )
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Any tips help thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be able to do something like this

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)



df = pd.read_csv('boilerData.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill').fillna(method = 'bfill')


app.layout = html.Div([

    html.H1('Heating System Temperature Data Visulation'), 
    html.Center('The purpose of the scatter plot below is to prove if a temperature reset strategy is implemented on the hydronic heating system. At various outside air temperature conditions, the hot water temperature should fluctuate to save energy.'),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='hwst-vs-oat',
        figure={
            'data': [
                go.Scatter(
                    x = df.OAT,
                    y = df.HWST,
                    mode = 'markers',
                    marker = dict(
                        color = '#FFBAD2',
                        line = dict(width = 1)
                    )
                )
            ],
            'layout':{
                'title':'Scatter Plot of OAT versus HWST',
                'xaxis':{
                    'title':'whatever you want x to be'
                },
                'yaxis':{
                    'title':'whatever you want y to be'
                }
            }
        }  
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: I edited my post to include my complete dash app.py file. Can help me out? Im getting syntax error `File "hwsScatter.py", line 45     )     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: looks like your missing a bracket somewhere

Comment: I edited my answer to put in everything with the syntax fix, you were missing a bracket down at the bottom as you can see I added a third bracket whereas you only had 2 basically you forgot to close figure

Comment: Yes thank you. One thing I notice is the script runs really slow. The data set maybe  on the large side... Is that a dash thing that is runs slow?

Comment: One other question if you would happen to know is it possible with dash to bring a calculated parameter up to the front end? I think I could this with Flask & Jinja... For example in dash maybe between an HTML div, would it be possible to show something like correlation between two points? IE, `correlation = df['HWST'].corr(df['OAT'])`

Comment: yes, you can definitely do that and I think you're doing it right I dont know exactly what your looking for but what you have there looks right, proper syntax I mean.